# How To use generate row number with group by option

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

The Input table DEDUPE

```
SOURCE  Legacy_vendor   Vendor  Condition application   Condition type  Doc type    
MX_PRISMA_PDN   9215217 1012473 EF                   ZNE1             ZMRO  
MX_PRISMA_PDN   9215217 1012473 EF                   ZNE1             ZNB   
MX_PRISMA_PDN   9215217 1012473 EF                   ZNE1             ZSRM
```

Output Should like

```
SOURCE  Legacy_vendor   Vendor  Condition application   Condition type  Doc type    
MX_PRISMA_PDN   9215217 1012473 EF                   ZNE1      ZMRO,ZNB,ZSRM
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: •Relational databases

Comment: Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.?

Comment: You need to tell us which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i am using MYSQL

Comment: Thank u all for ur Quick response

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE  #DEDUPE (SOURCE NVARCHAR(50),Legacy_vendor BIGINT,Vendor BIGINT ,[Condition application]  NVARCHAR(10),[Condition type] NVARCHAR(20),[Doc type]  NVARCHAR(20))


INSERT INTO #DEDUPE
SELECT 'MX_PRISMA_PDN' ,9215217, 1012473,'EF','ZNE1','ZMRO' UNION ALL
SELECT 'MX_PRISMA_PDN', 9215217, 1012473,'EF','ZNE1','ZNB' UNION ALL
SELECT 'MX_PRISMA_PDN', 9215217, 1012473,'EF','ZNE1','ZNB' 


    SELECT
    C.SOURCE,
    C.Legacy_vendor,C.Vendor,C.[Condition application],C.[Condition type],
        STUFF((  
                SELECT  ', ' +  CONVERT(Nvarchar,CP.[Doc type])
                FROM  
                #DEDUPE CP
                WHERE
                    C.SOURCE = CP.SOURCE
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') [Doc type]
    FROM
    #DEDUPE C 
    GROUP BY    C.SOURCE,
    C.Legacy_vendor,C.Vendor,C.[Condition application],C.[Condition type]

DROP TABLE #DEDUPE
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming SQL Server: You can do it using `XML` and `Stuff`

```
SELECT DISTINCT SOURCE,Legacy_vendor,Vendor,[Condition application],[Condition type],STUFF((SELECT ','+[Doc type]

            FROM Table1 T1
             WHERE T1.SOURCE=T2.SOURCE
                AND T1.Legacy_vendor=T2.Legacy_vendor
                AND T1.Vendor=T2.Vendor
             FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
             AS [Doc type]
FROM Table1 T2
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DNQSI16858)

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server

```
select source, legacy_vendor, vendor, condition_application, condition_type,
doctype = 
 STUFF((    SELECT ' '+ SUB.doctype AS [text()]  
FROM DEDUPE SUB  
WHERE  sub.source = main.source and  sub.legacy_vendor = main.legacy_vendor and
       sub.vendor = main.vendor and sub.condition_application= main.condition_application and sub.condition_type = main.condition_type
FOR XML PATH('') 
), 1, 1,'')  
 from DEDUPE main
 group by source, legacy_vendor, vendor, condition, condition_type
```

I used STUFF to join all the doc types in 1 column

Comment: Which dbms is this for?